# PHP - Mailchimp - Informations about subscribers

Tags: php, mailchimp

I work on a little page used to add susbcribers to a newsletter.
I use the function listSubscribe to add subscriber and I want to know if the mail send exist in the mailchimp list but i don't find how.
The function has a parameter update_existing but that don't return any information on the subscriber.

Somebody can help me ?

Comment: `listSubscribe` to add subscriber ??

Comment: It's not me who named the mailchimp API functions =/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you describe what you mean by "if the mail send exist"... are you wanting to be sure the address was added to the list?

http://apidocs.mailchimp.com/api/1.3/listmemberinfo.func.php

will return an empty array if the address is not on the list. (or details if it is)

"If the email send" could also mean something about the opt-in email,
but the response will be "true" from listSusbcribe if the address was added (passed validations)

Comment: Thank you. In fact I searched how to know if a mail is already in the list.I can use listMemberInfo to check the mail before send it.